# how to update data in table via combo in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and know only a couple of things.  I'm trying to make an application with data similar to the following:

```
team = [ {id:1, name: 'abc',type: 'cricket', country: 'usa'} ];
```

Displayed in a table, and I have a combo box which shows the list of countries.

What I would like to do is when I select a country from drop down the table should show only rows which match the country.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) with an [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

([Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dcu5rT1svPZ2vLofAEj5?p=preview))

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.13" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchCountry">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:{country: searchCountry}">
          <td>{{team.name}}</td>
          <td>{{team.type}}</td>
          <td>{{team.country}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.searchCountry = '';

    $scope.teams = [
      {id:1,name: 'abc' ,type: 'cricket' ,country: 'usa'},
      {id:1,name: 'def' ,type: 'cricket' ,country: 'canada'},
      {id:1,name: 'ghi' ,type: 'cricket' ,country: 'mexico'}
      ];


  });
```

**Edit**

The above uses a textbox for searching, which is not exactly what you asked.  If you wanted to use a combobox and only show exact matches it might look something like this:

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="c for c in countries">
  <option value="">(No Filter)</option>
</select>
...
<tr ng-repeat="team for team in teams | filter:filterFunction">
  ...
</tr>
```

.

```
/* controller */
$scope.countries = ['usa', 'mexico', 'canada'];
$scope.filterFunction = function(team) {
  /* no country selected or country matches */
  return (!$scope.country || team.country === $scope.country);
};
```